# "no module found" in python after installing module via pip

Tags: python, module, pip

I've been seeing the error `No module named 'ruamel'` when running a python script (with python3), even after running the command `pip3 install ruamel.yaml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the versions of pip and python were mismatched, so pip was installing the ruamel module onto python 3.8, but running python3 was using python 3.9

To diagnose the issue:

1. Check the python version being used with `python3 --version`
2. Check the pip version being used with `pip3 --version`

If the versions are different, you can call pip with the exact version number. For example, `pip3.9 install ruamel.yaml` to ensure that the module is installed onto the correct python version.